# What is the difference between this two syntax ko.observableArray([]) & ko.observableArray() knockout js

Tags: knockout.js

what is the difference between two below syntax

```
viewModel = {
    LoadedReports: ko.observableArray([]),
    Name: ko.observableArray()
}
```

what is the meaning of this `ko.observableArray([])` and this `ko.observableArray()`

when people declare observable Array with only bracket like `observableArray()` ?

and when people would go for `ko.observableArray([])`

need some knowledge. thanks

### edit

i saw again this

```
state: ko.observable(),
states: ko.observableArray(),
```

so what is the difference between `ko.observable() & ko.observableArray()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a minimal difference in terms of usage as far as the decalration goes both are same .

**Declaration :**

`LoadedReports: ko.observableArray()` --> empty array [] assigned

`LoadedReports: ko.observableArray([])`--> empty array [] assigned

**Usage :**

If you want to assign some data to observableArray onLoad we use `[]` notation with some data inside .

Sample **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9DHHh/655/)** demonstrates the same

Coming to the difference b/w ko.observable() & ko.observableArray()

> If you want to detect and respond to changes on one object, you’d use
>   observables. If you want to detect and respond to changes of a
>   collection of things, use an observableArray.

The above definition is straight from Docs you can refer **[here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html)**

I suggest you to go through complete Docs on ko before doing any sort of coding .

Answer (score 2):

they are the same,
the only reason you would use the square brackets is to initialize the array with data

```
loadedReports = ko.observableArray(['option','option2','etc']);
```

Comment: In other words you've just initialized the first example with an explicity empty array, the second is implicity (Knockout handles it under the hood).

Comment: what is the meaning of this line `loadedReports = ko.observableArray([]);`

Comment: and what is the meaning of this line what is the meaning of this line `loadedReports = ko.observableArray();` is it initialize with null ?

Comment: @Mou have you been to the knockout.js website? there's lots of documentation and sample code that would answer all of these questions you've been asking over the last few days.